# Parameter shown as "0:" in ajax request

Tags: ajax, django

```
 var frm = $('#updateStickyForm');

            frm.submit(function (e) {
                var id = "{{note.id}}"
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: frm.attr('method'),
                    url: frm.attr('action'),
                    data:
                    frm.serialize() + '&' + $.param(id),

                    success: function (data) {

                        console.log('Submission was successful.');
                        $('#test').show();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log('An error occurred.');
                        console.log(data);

                    },

                });
            });
```

When I look at the network logs in Chrome the parameter is shown as "0:". I'm able to access the parameter just fine with Django and do what I want to do with it, I just want to know how I can change it from "0" to something of my choosing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` seems to have a key `0` for the value you want to post, you can construct an object to pass to $.param with the key you want

```
frm.serialize() + '&' + $.param({"myid":id['0']}),
```

Comment: Thank you. This is just what I needed.